# How to see manpage of previous command?

Tags: bash, command-line, zsh

For example if I did a `curl -F 'clbin=@some-image.jpg' https://clbin.com`. How do I `man curl` easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both `bash` and `zsh` (and `(t)csh` where that feature comes from), provided that history expansion is enabled:

```
man !!:0
```

(admittedly, it's not really shorter than `man curl`).

Comment: You can shave off one more character and do `man !:0`.

Answer (score 3):

In `zsh`, easiest is to use [`run-help`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#Accessing-On_002dLine-Help).

Bring up your previous command (<kbd>Up</kbd>), and press <kbd>Alt+H</kbd>. That will bring up the documentation for `curl`.

Once you exit `man`, you'll be back to where you were. Very handy when you need to see the manual in the middle of typing a command.

Note that which documentation is displayed depends on where your cursor is on the command line. For instance, on a command line like:

```
echo test; cat file
     ^1        ^2  ^3
```

If you press <kbd>Alt-H</kbd> while your cursor is at 1, you'll see the `echo` manual, while you'll see the `cat` manual, if it's at 2 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

Other way is to play with bash hotkeys:

```
Up      return the last command onto bash edit line
Ctrl+A  move cursor to the begining of line
man     print command what you need
Alt+F   move cursor to the end of next word
Ctrl+K  delete all from the cursor till the end of line
```